# What is the result of this while-loop over a collection of integers?

Tags: java

Thank you for your time. I'm tutoring a student in high school computer science and am a little rusty with Java. The answer to the following practice problem is E according to the answer key.

Why should the answer be E?

Any insights are very much appreciated. Thank you.

Sample Problem:  Consider the following instance variable and method.

```
 private List<Integer> nums;

 / ** Precondition: nums.size > 0   */
 public void numQuest()
 {
     int k = 0;
     Integer zero = new Integer(0);
     while (k < nums.size())
     {
         if (nums.get(k).equals(zero))
             nums.remove(k);

         k++;
     }
 }
```

Assume that List nums initially contains the following 
Integer values.

[0, 0, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0]

What will List nums contain as a result of executing numQuest ?

(a) [0, 0, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0]

(b) [4, 2, 5, 3]

(c) [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 5, 3]

(d) [3, 5, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]

(e) [0, 4, 2, 5, 3]

Comment: You should step through this with a debugger.  The reason will become obvious.

Comment: I thought the answer was B, because the first two 0's would be removed.

Comment: I'm feeling I overlooked a small detail.

Comment: What is `k`? What happens to the `List` when you remove an element from it?

Comment: Just use the debugger.  Trust me.

Comment: Thank you. I have no access to a programming environment at the moment.

Comment: This is a great example of the necessary caution needed when iterating over a collection while simultaneously removing items from it.

Comment: Yeah, you could debug this with pencil and paper and see what's happening.  Unfortunately, @Sotirios has spoiled it for everyone :(

Comment: The importance of the caution needed in java and a debugger, is coming back to me. Thanks all.

Comment: It's not a problem. I remember now how a remove() affects elements of a List. Now I can accurately try it by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the start of your loop

```
k = 0
nums = [0, 0, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0]
```

(forget the notation)

```
nums[k] == nums[0] == 0
```

so we have to remove it. After the first iteration

```
k = 1
nums = [0, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0] // the first 0 was removed
```

Now

```
nums[k] == nums[1] == 4
```

so we don't remove it. You essentially skipped the 2nd element from the original list because you didn't take into account that the first element got removed. This is one reason you can't typically remove from a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: After I saw E as the answer, I had a feeling something changes with the list indices after a remove() is used in java. The explanation makes much sense now. Thank you.